# Variable scope for lock mechanism

Tags: c#, locking

Can someone explain in detail why scope of the variable being lock matter?
For example:

```
lock(variable){ //do something here ! }
```

In msdn, it states to avoid locking public type and best to lock private or private static type. During the locking, what is actually being lock? The variable address or what?

Comment: Please consider editing your question to match accepted answer. You have 3 questions in your post, but I accepted answer answers 1 out of 3. Also consider clarifying "scope" because I think you've used it in some other meaning than [C# variable scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `variable` is just some kind of a unique tag. Making it private avoid incidental locking with the same tag somewhere else.

And some comments regarding internal lock implementation can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/02/18/75454.aspx

Comment: Would you mind to clarify what question you've answered?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I meant that in `lock(variable)`, the `variable` is some kind of a unique entity. (It differentiates one lock from another lock, so some sort of "lock tag".) Perhaps the wording is not the best one :).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov P.S. To be more formal, my answer was for `why scope of the variable being lock matter` and link refers to `During the locking, what is actually being lock? The variable address or what?`

Answer (score 3):

`lock` accepts an instance of type `System.Object`. All instances of `System.Object` contain some hidden field in memory which is used for synchronization purposes (lets call it `ThreadId`). So, what happens when you call `lock` with some object? The `lock` statement (actually it is a syntax sugar for `Monitor.Enter`) checks whether the passed object has something in `ThreadId` field, and if it doesn't have anything, it puts there some identifier (id of current thread as far as I remember), enters the block of code under the `lock` statement and in the end of this block - resets the `ThreadId` value. If the ThreadId field is not empty, it stops and waits until it become empty. In such way it is guaranteed that only one thread can access the code section covered by `lock` with same passed object.

Why it is not recommended to use public properties/fields in `lock`? With locks, it is very easy to make a deadlock (when thread A waits for some action from thread B which in its turn waits for action from thread A). So, it is very important to control all locks made on same objects. When you design some class, you know about all private fields, only you can access them and only you can use them in locks. Once the field become public, you lose this control. Yes, you still can control all locks around this field inside your class, but you don't know how this field will be used by consumers of your class, they also can use it for locks and thus cause the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

If you lock on a private member in a particular object you are only locking in that instance. If you lock on a static field you will lock in all instances of the object.

Comment: I did not down vote, but the reason might be that in fact you can use any available object for locking. What you said is rather "best practice" that a formal restriction.

Comment: Hi, do you mean all the instances of the object will be locked and together with those code within the lock scope? If so, can you describe the back-end mechanism of how the lock get the mutual exclusive lock?

Comment: Possible answer: question could be read as "why instance / class scope matters for `lock`:  it is perfectly fine to lock on private instance or class variable - it completely depends on what the goal is.